# Adding all articles to a publication using TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, replication

I know you can do this easily using the GUI in SSMS. But,is there a way to include all the articles with TSQL instead of doing them one by one using sp_addarticle?

My initial idea is returning all the tables names(using a sys query) and then using a loop to feed them to sp_addarticle. I'm wondering if there's a smarter way for example a built-in variable that I can assign 'all' to it?

[image]

Comment: Add one table, click `Script` button. Get the template that you put in loop. Enjoy :)

Comment: @lad2025 For some reason the Scrip button is disabled. Is it because I have the developer edition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I did it

```
USE [DatabaseName]
DECLARE @name sysname
DECLARE @getid CURSOR


SET @getid = CURSOR FOR

-- Select all tables name
SELECT [name]
FROM [DataBaseName].[sys].[tables] 
WHERE is_ms_shipped=0

-- While loop
OPEN @getid
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getid INTO @name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
-- add article 
exec sp_addarticle  @publication =  @publication
    ,@article =  @name
    ,@source_object = @name
    ,@del_cmd = 'NONE' 

FETCH NEXT
FROM @getid INTO @name
END

CLOSE @getid
DEALLOCATE @getid
```